# path restriction for smartImage or smartFile

Tags: content-management-system, aem

can we restrict the path for smartimage or smartFile? Like when i drag an image from a specified path folder only in that case it gets added.

e.g. ddAccept and ddGroup

Answer (score 0):

Not that I understood fully how `smartfile` works, but from what I see: nope, you can't restrict that in the out-of-the-box version of the widget. There are no hints about this functionality: neither in the [documentation](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.SmartFile), nor in the source code (`/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/html5/form/SmartFile.js`).

I recommend, you extend SmartFile / SmartImage and override `#initializeDragAndDrop()` to add your logic there.

Comment: there is no method with this name in smartimage.

Can you plz elaborate it more. I'll be thankful to you.

Comment: that's in smart file; smart image extends smart file -- go to `/crxde` and check the file I linked; hope that makes some sense now?

Answer (score 0):

as an alternate you can use the pathfield xtype to take image location (href) in dialog . and in the pathfield set the rootpath to your desired node